# Why did this question got downvoted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, down-votes

[the question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712776/discrete-math-is-there-a-difference-between-subseteq-to-supseteq)
I understand that it's super-basic-preschool-stupid (actually no question is stupid) question, but is it right to down vote it just for that?

Few things that math taught me, is to question everything from the most abstractive idea to the smallest detail that nobody got will to deal with, doubt everything, never take things as they are etc...

I'm also sure it will be usefull as I'm definetly not the only one who asked about it, nor will ask about it in the future.

what made someone downvote it and is it right? Is it just his ego boost as his level is way superior for this kind of question to be around?

I know it's a **Trivial** question, it was meant to be one, I knew the answer before I asked it, the reason I asked it was becuase I wanted to be **sure**.

did my "research" and stumbled upon this [suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free), that suggest that downvotes for answers will cost 1 rep for you and 2 rep for the user who answered, and downvotes for question will just cost 2 downvotes for the user who posted the question.

I don't know if it's been done but, I extremely dissagree with it. I don't care that even one of the things that literally pops up when you hover on a downvote for a question says "This question does not show research value", the thing is, **there is no bad question** (maybe only if it's been posted, and that area is taken care of), but **there is a bad answer**.

questions should only be encouraged.

Comment: Voting is anonymous, so there is little point is asking why a question attracte a single downvote.

Comment: I agree with Michael... If you worry about all downvotes here, you will have no time for anything else!

Comment: Given the fact that your question has been answered and that you have never answered anyone's question on the network, it seems out of place to angrily demand that the people who answer your questions without getting anything from you in return have to encourage you while doing so.

Comment: I doubt that the downvoters disagree with giving you an answer, but a comment "Yes, here is the wiki link." does it. I do not think that your question is useful for anyone else because how would you have found it? You would not have. However, I do think that this issue should be dealt with by closing instead of by downvotes.

Comment: @Phira: I suppose that you mean the meta downvoters. I suspect that more than a handful of these are also a result of a now deleted comment by the OP that [justifiably] caused antagonism, which you may or may not have seen.

Comment: @Asaf You suppose wrongly. There is not even a wiki link in this meta thread. I am criticizing the tone and form of the meta post because the question that got down-votes was actually answered.

Comment: TL;DR As of 2021 you have 6 upvotes.

Answer (score 5):

The downvote mystifies me too... and I'm usually pretty imaginative at coming up with plausible explanations for such things even if I don't agree with them.

Regarding your last comment, it's not actually true that there are no bad questions; that advice is meant to encourage people who do have reasonable questions to ask, but are too shy or embarrassed to reveal their lack of knowledge or understanding about something, rather than to be a Universal Truth. However, the post you linked is exactly the sort of thing that advice is meant to encourage.

(there is some amount of debate about exactly what constitutes a bad question, and more specifically a bad question to ask *here* at MSE, so I won't try to elaborate, since that will simply derail this topic)

Comment: thank you, I agree (oddly ;) ), even if it's about lack of research, that is totally wrong, because this question doesn't show lack of research (show me a text book, or a website that compares subset sign to it's inverted form), actually it's a really trivial question that should be asked, whatever trivial it is, it's basic common sense to notice the most bizzare things, especially in math and logic field.

Answer (score -1):

That certainly is weird. Usually I see easy questions do get upvoted if you can sense eagerness on the asker's side to learn.

For one radical example, [here is kid trying to learn subtraction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703771/doing-take-aways). It has 8 upvotes as of now.

I upvoted it, and I strongly recommend you upvote it too, although I doubt that kid is coming back, it was heartwarming to see actually someone *trying to learn*.

Questions shouldn't  get downvoted just because they are easy. If that was the case, we would be on math overflow now, and this site wouldn't even *exist*.